# Python script gives IndexError

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

While running my script I get a sudden IndexError: List index out of range.
I get the first 17 items from the page that I want. Than all of a sudden I get the error.

I've tried everything that I could with my limited knowledge, but without succes.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import urllib

list_1 = []
TV_category = ["80"]
url_pattern = 'http://www.vandenborre.be/fr/tv-lcd-led/tv-lcd-led-{}-cm-tous-produits'

for item in TV_category:
    url = url_pattern.format(item)
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"lxml")


    g_data = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "product"})


    for item in g_data:
        product_price = item.contents[5].find_all("div", {"class": "prijs"})[0].text.encode("windows-1252").strip()
        product_ref = item.contents[3].find_all("h2")[0].text
        overzicht=[product_ref, product_price]
        list_1.append(overzicht)
        outfile = open("./nvdb.csv", "wb")
        writer = csv.writer(outfile)
        writer.writerow(["Product","Prijs"])
        writer.writerows(list_1)
```

Comment: Why do you think Python is lying?

Comment: I don't think Python is lying, just don't understand why I get suddenly this error in after the script returns the first 17 items. I had the same issue with an other side. The work around that I found was that when I displayed only 12 items per page and than crawl each page I could get all the results. But I really want to understand why it stops at 17 results.

Comment: Your code has 4 indexing operations. Obviously one of them is failing.

Comment: Even when I print g_data I only get 17 results

Comment: Executing the code as is - getting 146 products.